# Generate example data variance and biased variance

Tags: probability-or-statistics, education

I'd like to generate some example data for this equation related to Bessel's correction. What is a way to generate data for first part of the equation (in the picture below). One way to approach is to come up with a vector, like x= {1,2,3} and do the Expected Value of Variance[x] - the biased variance. But, I had trouble understanding whether the Variance function uses n-1, so would it be the sigma^2 or Sbiased^2?

That is, in some way it would be ExpectedValue{x - sbiased}, where x is a matrix of something like x={{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}}.

I'm new to Mathematica (and stack  overflow mathematica) and appreciate any help and advice if I posted a question in the wrong way. Thank you

[image]

Comment: you might want to consider it posting on the mathematics forum because it seems like you do not have any problem with the code but the mathematics (for which there is a dedicated forum).

Comment: tom, if you agree with Ali Hashmi I can move your question to [Math.SE]; let me know in these comments, or **flag** your post for moderator attention.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I want to make sure people in mathematics can tell me how to do it in mathematica. If that's the case, sure, please migrate it to any forum you think is best

Comment: You would have to know the population mean $\mu$, and the distribution that the data comes from, in order to generate some sample data. If you would like to specify the distribution (e.g. $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ ), then the question can be answered. You might also want to change your question from seeking the 'best' way, to different ways ... since 'best' is a restriction you probably don't intend, and hard to pin down.

Comment: Thanks @wolfies. I'm happy with something much simpler than a parametric distribution. It could be a 3x3 matrix of something like {1,2,3} etc. I will change the word "best"

Comment: Well, that is where your question gets confusing. The $\mu$ in the equation refers to the mean of the population. The xbar refers to the sample mean. So, you need to distinguish between some sample data (which we can generate from a known distribution with `RandomVariate`), the sample mean of that data, and the population mean. If you provide a matrix of data, in what way is the population mean any different to the sample mean?

Comment: sure. what if I created a matrix of simple data (say a 3x3 or single digit numbers). Then, how would i generate the example from that?

Comment: If you provide a table of data, you have to decide if that is the POPULATION, or a SAMPLE from the population. If it is a SAMPLE, then you still to need to know what is the population mean, which requires either knowing all the data, or knowing the distribution it comes from.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue it raises is not a Mathematica issue but a mathematics issue.

Answer (score 1):

If the aim is illustrative, perhaps:

```
r[n_, k_] := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {n, k}]
e[n_, k_] := Variance[Mean /@ rv[n, k]]
Manipulate[
 Show[DiscretePlot[e[n, s], {n, 100, 10000, 100}], 
  Plot[1/x, {x, 1, 10000}, PlotStyle -> Red]], {s, {10, 100, 1000}}]
```

[image]